# Random headphone/icon bug? LG G3 running Sprint Android Lollipop 5.0.1

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, lg, headphones, bugs

Last night, when I was attempting to use my headphones, the first 3 times I inserted them, they were detected by my phone as an Auxiliary Cable. The 4th time, however, it correctly detected them as headphones. I've plugged my headphones in 6 or 7 times since then, and the issue hasn't happened again; I was just wondering if this is a common bug, or if I should be worried about the headphone jack failing.

Comment: Do you have old/spare working headphone? (Can be arranged from a friend too.) You could test them to see if it is a bug or jack failing.

Comment: Firelord, what do you mean? I have headphones that work just fine, several pairs actually; I've tried multiple pairs (I've plugged headphones in and taken them out) about 12 times today and it hasn't happened again. Would that mean it's just an odd random bug?

Answer (score -1):

Basically, the Linux switch driver will raise the event to Android. I suspect that your headset jack insertion circuit failed.